# How to fix vector assignment (vlog-13069) error

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

My variable declarations are like below:

```
output [6:0] dout_7seg_3, dout_7seg_2, dout_7seg_1, dout_7seg_0;    
wire   [6:0] dout_7seg [3:0];
```

and I tried to assign each `dout_7seg_i` to `dout_7seg [i]` by coding like below:

```
assign dout_7seg_3 = dout_7seg [6:0][3];
```

I got error results like this:

> **Error: (vlog-13069) "[": syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ';' or ','.**

I also tried to use a `generate` block:

```
genvar i;
generate for (i = 0; i<7; i = i+1) begin
    assign dout_7seg_3 = dout_7seg [i:0][3]; //I wanted to code like dout_7seg_i = dout_7seg [6:0][i]
    end
endgenerate
```

and also had the same

> **vlog-13069 error**

Can you help me fix these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are assigning all 7 bits, there is no need to use the packed range (`[6:0]`).  Simply use:

```
assign dout_7seg_3 = dout_7seg[3];
assign dout_7seg_2 = dout_7seg[2];
assign dout_7seg_1 = dout_7seg[1];
assign dout_7seg_0 = dout_7seg[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you messed up the order of indexing. It should look like the following:

```
assign dout_7seg_3 = dout_7seg [3][6:0];
```

The packed dimension goes last.